# Logging in to Garmin Connect from C#

Tags: c#, http, garmin

I have a code to login to GarminConnect.com however garmin chose to change their login process so my code doesn't work anymore and I'm lost on how to get it to work again.

I'm not usually developing web communication applications so it does not make much sence to me how I should proceed to get it working again.

This is what I have now:

```
public class SessionService
{
    private const string SignInUrl = @"https://connect.garmin.com/en-US/signin";
    private const string DashboardUrl = @"http://connect.garmin.com/dashboard";

    public Session Session { get; private set; }

    public bool SignIn(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            Session = new Session();
            GetSignInPage(Session.Cookies);

            var signInResponse = PostSignInRequest(Session.Cookies, userName, password);

            if (IsDashboardUri(signInResponse.ResponseUri))
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error signing in. {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        var request = HttpUtils.CreateRequest(BuildSignOutUrl(), Session.Cookies);
        request.GetResponse();
    }

    private static string BuildSignOutUrl()
    {
        var queryString = HttpUtils.CreateQueryString();
        queryString.Add("actionMethod", "page/home/dashboard.xhtml:identity.logout");
        queryString.Add("cid", "");
        return String.Format("{0}?{1}", DashboardUrl, queryString);
    }

    private static void GetSignInPage(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        var request = HttpUtils.CreateRequest(DashboardUrl, cookies);
        request.GetResponse();
    }

    private static HttpWebResponse PostSignInRequest(CookieContainer cookies, string userName, string password)
    {
        var formBinaryData = BuildSignInFormData(userName, password);

        var request = HttpUtils.CreateRequest(SignInUrl, cookies);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.WriteBinary(formBinaryData);
        return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    }

    private static byte[] BuildSignInFormData(string userName, string password)
    {
        var formParams = HttpUtils.CreateQueryString();
        formParams.Add("login", "login");
        formParams.Add("login:loginUsernameField", userName);
        formParams.Add("login:password", password);
        formParams.Add("login:signInButton", "Sign In");
        formParams.Add("javax.faces.ViewState", "j_id1");
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formParams.ToString());
    }

    private static bool IsDashboardUri(Uri uri)
    {
        return uri.ToString().StartsWith(DashboardUrl);
    }
}
```

I hope someone is able to point me in the right direction on how to get this working

Comment: First of all, what did you mean "code doesn't work anymore"?

Comment: Well.. Garmin changed their authentication procedure and then my code stopped working..

Comment: Need details. In which line your code stopped working? How Garmin changed the procedure? Without the information, you question can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Garmin seems to be rendering an iframe through JS.  I doubt doing a basic form post is going to handle this as Javascript needs to run to build DOM elements.  You should reach out to Garmin to work with their API.

Comment: As of today an official Garmin Connect API is "Coming Soon." http://developer.garmin.com/